# Compiling problem : In function `_start': undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I'm getting following error:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/glibc-6V9RKT/glibc-2.19/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: undefined reference to`main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

used g++:

g++ -Wall main.cpp plzsucheclass1.cpp -o listentest

this is my main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "plzsucheclass.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int eingabe;
  cout << "Wollen Sie die Suchfunktion fuer PLZ/Ort oder die Entfernung zwischen zwei Gebieten berechnen? " << '\n';
  cout << '\n' << "Geben Sie 0 fuer Suchen und 1 fuer Berechnen ein ! " << '\n';
  cout << '\n' << "Geben Sie 2, um das Programm zu beenden, ein !" << '\n' << '\n';
  cin >> eingabe;
  LesenSchreiben l;
  SuchenBerechnen sb;

  switch (eingabe) {
  case 0:
    l.datei_bdlEinlesen();
    sb.plzortSuchen(l);
    break;
  case 1:
    l.datei_laebrEinlesen();
    sb.sucheEntfernung(l);
    break;
  case 2:
    exit(0);
  default:
    cerr << '\n' << "Keine korrekte Auswahl getroffen, bitte erneut versuchen !!!" << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It would be nice, if you could help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your error after creating a simple `main()` function and an empty `plzsucheclass1.cpp`:

```
$ cat >> main.cpp
int main() {
    return 0;
}
$ cat >> plzsucheclass1.cpp

$ g++ -Wall main.cpp plzsucheclass1.cpp -o listentest
$ ./listentest 
$ ./listentest && echo "Success"
Success
```

I suspect your build command is not exactly what you have posted here.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was making my first C++ program and it was due to the fact that I did not save it before compiling it. So try saving it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're accurately describing the problem, there's only one way that error can happen.

The most likely explanation is that you're not being accurate. Either your build command is not `g++ -Wall main.cpp plzsucheclass1.cpp -o listentest` or the `main.cpp` you showed is not the one you are compiling (maybe you ran the `g++` command in a different directory with a different `main.cpp`?)

The other option is that your `plzsucheclass1.hpp` header defines `main` as a macro and so causes `int main()` to be replaced with something else. Don't do that.